# Why DigestOutputStream cast int to byte?

Tags: java, md5

The `DigestOutputStream` calculates hash of its content, for example MD5 hash. If we look at its source we'll see:

```
public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    digest.update((byte)b);
    out.write(b);
}
```

It casts `int` (32 bits) to `byte` (8 bits). Is it ok to do such casting?

Comment: It's ok if you only need the lowest eight bits. consider `Integer.toString(255, 2)`... that's a `String` of 8 ones.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't the hashing algorithm calculate the hash over all the bits - to be more sensitive to the content changes?

Comment: That depends on whether the high order bits are ever set. Also, this is a specific hashing algorithm. And if the hash output is consistent with other implementations and it is, then I think we can assume it's not using the high order bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract of `OutputStream.write(int)` is that it writes the lowest 8 bytes of the argument. There is no mystery here. If the `OutputStream` was writing to a file, the same thing would happen.